# how to achieve an apache Alias with a proxy pass on the same domain

Tags: node.js, wordpress, apache

We have a NodeJS site running with an Apache VirtualHost that looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName      domain.org
    ServerAlias www.domain.org

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8884/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8884/

    ProxyPreserveHost on

    LogLevel debug
</VirtualHost>
```

This works fine.

however we have now been tasked with installing a wordpress blog as an alias of the domain

[www.domain.org/blog](http://www.domain.org/blog)

To do this we tried setting up a vhost with an Alias like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       Alias /blog /var/apache-vhosts/www.domain.org-blog

       <Directory /var/apache-vhosts/www.domain.org-blog/>
           Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
           AllowOverride All
           Order allow,deny
           allow from all
       </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

We have the mod_alias apache module enabled but it just wont pick it up.

Has anyone else achieved this?

I have also tried including the alias without a vhost wrapping tag but still no joy :/

Comment: if you have both virtualhosts enabled the first will always be used -> and therefor you can never reach the /blog alias. If you want the proxy and the alias on the same domain you will have to have both in the same virtualhost

Comment: is there a way to achieve this at all then?

Comment: I'm not allowed to set the "apache" tag as primary one. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Note that `ProxyPass` has precedence over `Alias`.

To fix, declare another `ProxyPass` pointing to an exclamation mark (`!`).

For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName      domain.org
    ServerAlias www.domain.org
   
    # the next line is your fix
    ProxyPass /blog !
    Alias     /blog /var/apache-vhosts/www.domain.org-blog

    <Directory /var/apache-vhosts/www.domain.org-blog/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


    ProxyPass        / http://localhost:8884/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8884/
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    LogLevel debug
</VirtualHost>
```

You can find more information in the official `ProxyPass` documentation:

> The ! directive is useful in situations where you don't want to reverse-proxy a subdirectory
> ― https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html

Comment: Just a little point, You should NOT wrap  `<Location>` derivative around ProxyPass when using this method, It will not work.